# Problem with drone simulator // [cvg_sim_test] is not a package or launch file name

Tags: ros, tum-ardrone, rosmake, tum-simulator, ardrone2.0

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
i tried to install package [tum_simulator](http://wiki.ros.org/tum_simulator) but I found one problem.
When I try to run simulator:

```
roslaunch cvg_sim_test 3boxes_room.launch
```

i get:

```
[cvg_sim_test] is not a package or launch file name
```

I have ROS fuerte and installed gazebo 1.6, rviz.

I was adding step by step packages:
ardrone_autonomy package, joy_node and ardrone_joystick packages, tum_simulator package.
I used 'rosmake' and I didn't get any error.

My workspace looks:

> przemek@przem:~/fuerte_workspace$ ls
> ardrone_autonomy  sandbox     setup.sh
> simulator_gazebo  visualization
> ardrone_helpers   setup.bash
> setup.zsh  tum_simulator

When I call echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
I get:

> /home/przemek/fuerte_workspace/simulator_gazebo:/home/przemek/fuerte_workspace/sandbox:/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks:/opt/ros/fuerte/share:/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros:/home/przemek/fuerte_workspace/ardrone_autonomy:/home/przemek/fuerte_workspace/ardrone_helpers:/home/przemek/fuerte_workspace/ardrone_helpers:/home/przemek/fuerte_workspace/tum_simulator

there is almost everything apart from rviz.

Please help me.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194973/problem-with-drone-simulator-//-%5Bcvg_sim_test%5D-is-not-a-package-or-launch-file-name/) by [green96](https://answers.ros.org/users/20466/green96/) on ROS Answers with karma: 115 on 2014-10-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like the tum_simulator repository has a 'fuerte' branch which includes the cvg_sim_test package. Have you tried that version?

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-10-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [green96](https://answers.ros.org/users/20466/green96/) on 2014-10-16**:
I was doing exactly what is on http://wiki.ros.org/tum_simulator.
So I cloned from git this link:

```
https://github.com/tum-vision/tum_simulator.git
```

now I see that it has **branch master** and below we can find info that it is for **hydro.**

**Comment by [green96](https://answers.ros.org/users/20466/green96/) on 2014-10-16**:
So if i have ros-fuerte I should clone from this link?

```
https://github.com/tum-vision/tum_simulator/tree/fuerte
```

(Sorry for double comment but there is limit of characters..)

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-10-16**:
No. You already have a copy of the repository on your machine; you just need to check out the 'fuerte' branch. Try: `roscd tum_simulator` and `git checkout fuerte`

**Comment by [green96](https://answers.ros.org/users/20466/green96/) on 2014-10-16**:
Thank you so much for your help, unfortunately before you wrote your answer I had reinstalled my ROS to Indigo version and just now successfully run simulator. :)
So I can't check it, but conclusion is to clone from git using parameter -b, for example: -b indigo